# loading sidecar is really slow (cloud run)

Tags: google-cloud-run

I am trying cloud run sidecar https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-multi-container-deployments

My problem is a docker that loads quickly as a standalone cloud run loads very slow when it is deployed as a sidecar along with ingress container. I am not sure what is going on.

My container doesn't consume much resources and as a standalone cloud run, I deploy with the following command:

```
gcloud run deploy CLOUD_RUN_NAME \
    --image=MY_TEST_CONTAINER \
    --memory=256Mi \
    --cpu=0.25
```

When I deploy the container as a sidecar, I use service.yaml (gcloud run services replace service.yaml) which is:

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    run.googleapis.com/launch-stage: BETA
  name: foo
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        run.googleapis.com/execution-environment: gen1
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: INGRESS_IMAGE
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "0.25"
              memory: 256Mi
        - image: MY_TEST_CONTAINER
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "1"
              memory: 512Mi
```

Here MY_TEST_CONTAINER is the same container. I am logging when the container is ready to listen with the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    logger.info(f"Starting service on port {port}")
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)))
```

As a sidecar it takes 7 minutes (and as a standalone it takes a second or two). I am not sure why. Can anyone help what changes I need to make?

EDIT: The following toy code takes minutes to load as a sidecar. On any machine it loads in a second.

```
import logging
import os

import google.cloud.logging
from flask import Flask
from flask import make_response
from flask import request
from google.cloud import firestore
from waitress import serve

# problems
from langchain import OpenAI
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor
from langchain.agents import BaseSingleActionAgent
from langchain.agents import Tool
from langchain.schema import AgentAction
from langchain.schema import AgentFinish

app = Flask(__name__)
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
client.setup_logging()

@app.route("/foo", methods=["POST"])
def foo():
    d = request.get_json()
    logging.info(f"params: {d}")

    return make_response("ok", 200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    logging.info(f"Starting service on port {port}")
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)))
```

EDIT2: For now I am switching to GKE with sidecar as things are fast on GKE.

EDIT3: One should add startup probe for sidecar to load quickly (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks#http-startup-probe)

Comment: I filed a bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/291825578

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the bug is with programming logic and is not a Cloud Run issue.

Comment: I disagree as my toy example has the same problem. Importing langchain is not really compute intensive. Even on a gcp cloud shell they get imported in a second. Again the problem only occurs when the service is deployed as a sidecar in addition to a ingress container. If it is deployed alone everything loads quick.

Comment: What problem does your new example have? Show the Cloud Run logs and other technical details to show the problem. I have a feeling that you have severely **under-allocated** resources to your container to support OpenAI. You state `On any machine it loads in a second`. Demonstrate that you are comparing apples-to-apples. What is the Cloud Run configuration? What is the configuration of the other system? Show the build and deploy commands. Show the test and the test results for both systems.

Answer (score 0):

From your bug report details: Your problem is caused by running a for loop reading from Firestore as part of the application startup. You are initializing the Firestore client inside the for loop. Initializing the client is expensive and there is no caching of authorization credentials, connection handles, etc. You have an application programming bug, not a Cloud Run bug.

This is the problem code:

```
for i in range(100):
    db = firestore.Client()
    doc = db.collection("hello").document("hi").get()
```

You should do something like this and this code is not optimized:

```
db = firestore.Client()
for i in range(100):
    doc = db.collection("hello").document("hi").get()
```

Comment: I deliberately made this problem. The loop runs fine in a typical cloud run service setting, i.e. no sidecar. It only becomes a problem when the loop runs in a sidecar.

Comment: @DokookChoe - It is still a problem no matter the reason. It is not a bug with Cloud Run. It is a bug you created in your code.

Comment: Thanks. In my dev code, I got rid of initializing db multiple times and it is still slow when it is deployed as a sidecar. I suspect when heavy operations are called initially, the cloud run is having trouble loading it up as a sidecar.

Comment: I found that importing langchain libraries at the beginning causes the same problem. I will update the bug report

Comment: @DokookChoe - if you study best practices for serverless containers, one of the goals is to minimize global operations that occur during startup. You want the container to start up as fast as possible to be ready to service requests. Failure to follow that guideline can result in poorly performing distributed services, failed health checks, and more. The issue that I have with your example is that you deliberately created a problem and then cried wolf. Submit correctly designed code and then if you have a problem engineers will look into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, adding startup probe (in yaml for cloud run) fixes the problem (according to GCP support team).

startup probe: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks#http-startup-probe

Here's a simple example of how to set up cloud run with sidecar: https://github.com/cdg720/cloud_run_sidecar

Comment: Show the actual changes you made.

Comment: https://github.com/cdg720/cloud_run_sidecar/commit/29baa197b6ff08942dc2c13bfa1aecec8519ef13

Comment: Answers must be self-contained with no requirement to go to another site. Links break, contents change, etc.  Links for reference are fine. Show the actual change with an explanation/details that was required to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using startup probe fixes the issue here is an example yaml config for a backend service.

```
    - image: mta1711/tasks-app-back
      name: hello
      env:
        - name: PORT
          value: "8080"
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 1000m
          memory: 512Mi
      startupProbe:
        tcpSocket:
          port: 8080
        timeoutSeconds: 240
        periodSeconds: 240
        failureThreshold: 2
```